# How to launch a single application on Nvidia card with proprietary driver on 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

At the very beginning of the support of Optimus technology on Ubuntu, there was Bumblebee, that could launch a single application on the dedicated Nvidia card, while leaving the rest of the system on integrated Intel.

Bumblebee was always a temporary project and has been - in principle - superseeded by the full support of Prime (last release was in 2013, so dead project right now).

Now I can change the card from the Nvidia Settings application, logout and login and the *whole* system uses my dedicated card.

This is something that I would like to avoid. I am on a laptop, working, doing stuff, than I want to play some games for some time, or edit some photos. Log off and then login again takes some time, then when I finish I have to revert back, if I forget everything starts heating up after some hours...

So, the question is how do I achieve the same result as bumblebee (launching a single application on dedicated GPU) on 16.04 with proprietary Nvidia drivers (340)?

In more details, this is my `lspci`

```
$ lspci -nn | grep '\[03'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
02:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev ff)
```

and I would like to use Darktable and Steam games on the Nvidia card.

Comment: This is a start for what you want http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html it is an indicator for switching between Intel and Nvidia quickly. As far as I can tell, prime will not work on a per application basis, you could install `bumblebee` at the same time and use `optirun` but it may cause issues.

Comment: Mh... Thanks but that is just a fast way to log out and switch card, that is definitely not what I want here. I might resort to that if there is no other solution, but since also it is a 2 years old article for the development version of 14.04 that needs an external repo... I'll wait a bit more to try it :)

Answer (score 0):

[Nvidia supports `PRIME` since 435.17 version](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PRIME#PRIME_render_offload), except there's a nuance that plainly setting `DRI_PRIME=1` wouldn't quite work. Instead you can use [this one-liner script](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/nvidia-prime/-/blob/main/prime-run?ref_type=heads) as¹:

```haskell
$ sudo wget https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/nvidia-prime/-/raw/main/prime-run\?ref_type\=heads -O /usr/bin/prime-run
[…]
$ prime-run glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
```

Worth mentioning that Ubuntu also has a `nvidia-prime` package with an utility `/sbin/prime-offload`, but its content is quite involved compared to the `prime-run` one-liner, so I suspect it might be building up some workarounds for the case where NVidia driver has no PRIME support. Workarounds in general tend to have problems, so I can't recommend that utility.

---

1: For posterity, as of writing the words the content of `prime-run` is just:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia "$@"
```