# Switch Nvidia Prime without logging out

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime

I run a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 on a new laptop with GTX 960m and Intel i7 and using the recommended proprietary drivers in the **Additional Drivers** settings is working well.

However, I was a little disappointed to realise that to switch from the Nvidia drivers back to the Intel display drivers for battery life required changing a setting in **Nvidia X Server Settings** and then **logging out**, ie. does not dynamically switch based on demand and power requirements.

Is there work towards a system that dynamically switches the hybrid graphics? I have seen the Bumblebee project briefly, does this attempt this? Are the future drivers in **ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa** going in this direction?

Thanks!

Comment: The loading of Nvidia drivers for a single application on Ubuntu 16.04 is asked in http://askubuntu.com/questions/778971/how-to-launch-a-single-application-on-nvidia-card-with-proprietary-driver-on-16 that currently has no answers

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, this's a problem with X server. There are no means of switching between devices while the X server is running.

Bumblebee used 2 instances of X server being used in the same time and switch buffers between them. This attempt was just a workaround of the problem and it suffers from excessive overhead.

Answer (score 0):

bumblebee will allow you to start specific applications with the nvidia card providing the graphics acceleration for that application only.  all other applications continue using the Intel GPU.  it's not dynamic switching but it's better than nothing.

you invoke an application as follows:

```
primusrun application
```

Comment: Bumblebee hasn't worked correctly since 14.04. It's broken some systems and has just not worked on others. I would not recommend trying this.

Comment: That is the suspician I had although I hadn't tried, there hasn't been development since April 2013 https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee